# Change highlight color/tint of selected button and notification bar from purple to custom

Tags: xml, android-studio, button, highlight, navigationbar

I have implemented bottom navigation bar in Android studio

The screenshot of my app is
[image: As you can see when the home button is selected it is highlighted using a purplish capsule and the navigation bar is also highlighted in purple due to some reason]
Please help me to change/remove the default purple highlights from my app.

The xml code of the menu is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_home_24"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/courses"
        android:title="Courses"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_menu_book_24"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:title="Profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_person_24"/>
</menu>
```

The activity_main.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemTextColor="#0FFF50"
        app:itemIconTint="#0FFF50"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/btm_nav_menu" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

I tried looking for any parameter of the xml code set to purple but could not find any. Also android studio seems to like purple as the default color of buttons is purple.